# Changing header cart text in Storefront

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I would like to edit the text in the header mini cart in Storefront theme:
'X items'
to just :
'X'
http://demo.woothemes.com/storefront/

Where can I access this? Can't find it anywhere in storefront or woocommerce files. I can see hook in header.php:
storefront_header_cart
but can't find any function for this in other files?

I would like to remove the dropdown when you hover over it too. Where can I change this?

Comment: Mini cart is Ajax JQuery JS based, start looking in theme or Woocommerce JS files. You need to turn on debug mode to load non-minified versions of JS files.

Comment: The mini cart is ajax, but it ultimately still loads a regular template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that functionality is handled by `storefront_cart_link` function...

you can override the function... open functions.php... look for `require get_template_directory() . '/inc/init.php';`

right above it, paste this code...

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'storefront_cart_link' ) ) {
    function storefront_cart_link() {
        ?>
            <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo esc_url( WC()->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart', 'storefront' ); ?>">
                <?php echo wp_kses_data( WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal() ); ?> <span class="count"><?php echo wp_kses_data( sprintf( '%d', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) );?></span>
            </a>
        <?php
    }
}
```

`storefront_cart_link` is loaded with this call `require get_template_directory() . '/inc/init.php';`. So above will load first, making it not create that function anymore with the call of `require get_template_directory() . '/inc/init.php';`.

This will do the trick.. but better use child theme... you can just paste directly the function above on the child theme's functions.php. functions.php on a child theme will load first than that of the parent, so making your function exist first.

Comment: Thank you for detailed reply. I have added this function to my child theme functions.php but it has no effect at all. I added test class to the span element and it is not appearing on front end either. Does it make a difference where the function is placed? I also tried without the if condition, with no avail (was wondering why there is 'if does not exist?)

Comment: @yennefer, have you tried it on the parent theme? just to test...Ideally we need that function before the `require get_template_directory() . '/inc/init.php';`

Comment: Thanks, for some reason the changes I've made to the child theme and my test appeared after of couple of days.. Some caching issue I guess, your first answer was spot on.

Comment: As of today, storefront´s current version does not even have that init.php call in functions.php, I pasted your code in it anyway and nothing happened. Any clues?