# Remove word from Woocommerce count span in cart header

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Does somebody know, where I can find the `.php` file in woocommerce, where I can remove the word "item" or "items" from the last span?

I've tried it with some jQuery Code but it only works when I load the page completely. When I click add to cart or remove from cart an item, the cart only reload in woocommerce without my `.js` file to remove the two words.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you

```js
$('.count').html($('.count').html().replace(' items',''));
$('.count').html($('.count').html().replace(' item',''));
```

```html
<a class="cart-contents" href="http://*****.de/warenkorb/" title="View your shopping cart">
<span class="amount">0,00&nbsp;€</span>
<span class="count">0 items</span><!--Here I want to remove the Word items to show just the number-->
</a>
```

Comment: can you provide your website link ?

Comment: It's currently offline because my boss dont like this :/ it's currently not official thats a problem... i know

Comment: OK the "item " showing in mini cart ? I means where is showing item word and where is showing items word ?

Comment: something showing like this website http://stagingdb.boardgamerepublic.com.au/product/10-days-in-europe/  please clear it ?

Comment: Remove $ not found an error from JS. use jQuery instead of $.

Comment: i've found a website with the same cart on the site: http://www.shultzilla.com/ there you can see that he edit thes words after cart and i just want to show "1" without "items" behind the 1

Comment: @WisdmLabs I know... thats not the main problem on my site i have this like you said. The Problem is the word items after the cart counter

Comment: I've found a question with the same problem but i looks like that the also dont solved it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443379/changing-header-cart-text-in-storefront

Comment: /**
 * Filter to remove the word 'item'/'items' from WP Menu Cart
 */
add_filter( 'wpmenucart_menu_item_a_content', 'wpmenucart_remove_items_caption', 10, 1 );
function wpmenucart_remove_items_caption($menu_item_a_content) {
 global $wpMenuCart;
 $item_data = $wpMenuCart->shop->menu_item();
 $item_text = sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $item_data['cart_contents_count'], 'wpmenucart'), $item_data['cart_contents_count']);
 $menu_item_a_content = str_replace( $item_text, $item_data['cart_contents_count'], $menu_item_a_content);
 return $menu_item_a_content;
}

Comment: I've tried but I don't use this plugin....my minicart is already included in my thene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of breaking my head about this i've found a solution *(I'm so happy and angry too because when you know the answer the solution is so easy)*.

First you have to find the file woocommerce/templates/cart/mini-cart.php to overwrite our function.

When you've found it you have to find following line:

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', '<span class="quantity">' . sprintf( '%s &times; %s', $cart_item['quantity'], $product_price ) . '</span>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?></li>
```

After you've found it you have to insert following code under the line:

```php
<?php

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment' );
    function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
        ob_start();
?>
        <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo esc_url( WC()->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart', 'storefront' ); ?>">
            <span class="count"><?php echo sprintf (_n( '%d', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?></span>
        </a> 
<?php

        $fragments['a.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();

        return $fragments;
    }
?>
```

Now you have to save the file and reload the page and put something in your cart (or remove) to update your cart. Know it should be done! :-)

If you want to add your price to the header too you also have to add above `<span class="count">` following lines of code:

```html
<span class="amount"><?php echo wp_kses_data( WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal() ); ?></span>
```

If you have any questions you can always comment me…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thank You ;) :D

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the risk of these adjustments being overwritten if you update Storefront, you can also rewrite the function in your functions.php file like this:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'storefront_cart_link' ) ) {
    function storefront_cart_link() {
        ?>
            <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'View your shopping cart', 'storefront' ); ?>">
                <?php /* translators: %d: number of items in cart */ ?>
                <?php echo wp_kses_post( WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal() ); ?> <span class="count"><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?></span>
            </a>
        <?php
    }
}
```